# google map shows random location as center, even when center is specified

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm using the package google-maps-react to show gmaps in my react app. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the map initially shows a random location as the center, even when I've specified co-ordinates for the center and initial center. How can I fix this so that the map centers on the co-ordinates I've specified initially?

```
const MapContainer = React.memo((props) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 59.913, lng: 10.752 });
  var bounds = new props.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  const setMapObj = (mapProps, map) => {
    setMap(map);
  };

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    if (props.markers.length === 1) {
      setCenter(props.markers[0]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < props.markers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(
        new props.google.maps.LatLng(props.markers[i].lat, props.markers[i].lng)
      );
    }
    if (map) {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }, [props.markers, map]);

  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      {/* TODO -> Store api key in .env file */}
      {console.log(center)}
      <Map
        google={props.google}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
        center={center}
        initialCenter={center}
        onReady={setMapObj}
        zoom={4}
        bounds={bounds}
      >
        {props.markers.map((item, index) => {
          if (item.lat && item.lng)
            return (
              <Marker key={index} position={{ lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng }} />
            );
        })}
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is trying to set a center AND fit a particular bounds. The latter will cause the center to change in order to fit all of the markers in the viewport.

Comment: Yes, what I want is to show the specified center initially, as no markers will be present at the start. When markers are added, I want the center to change in order to show all the markers.

Comment: Your code doesn't do that though. It always fitsBounds when the map has been instantiated.